# Percentage PriceScale shows strange text on negative percentage

Tags: lightweight-charts

When I display the PriceScale it shows me some strange characters on labels that are under 0%. Has anyone else experienced this? Does anybody know the solution? Thanks!

[image: 1]

I'm using version 3.8.0 of LightweightCharts. I am using the chart in Percentage mode

Comment: Could you please provide an example on a code sandbox site like JSFiddle? Here is an example I created with v3.8 and it appears to work correctly. https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/lightweight-charts-js-starter-forked-yecvcu

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be related to file encoding; in my use case, I was reading a .js file into python and displaying it in a webview. What solved it was ensuring that I was reading the file with the same encoding as the files encoding. In my case it needed to be read as UTF-8, which is not the default encoding type on Windows.